# Regular Expression matching a string of specified length

Tags: regex

I want to write a regular expression that matches all 9-letter words in a word list that contain only one vowel; for example, "strengths".

The best I've achieved is:

```
^(([^aeiou]{8}[aeiou])|
([^aeiou]{7}[aeiou][^aeiou]{1})|
([^aeiou]{6}[aeiou][^aeiou]{2})|
([^aeiou]{5}[aeiou][^aeiou]{3})|
([^aeiou]{4}[aeiou][^aeiou]{4})|
([^aeiou]{3}[aeiou][^aeiou]{5})|
([^aeiou]{2}[aeiou][^aeiou]{6})|
([^aeiou]{1}[aeiou][^aeiou]{7})|
([aeiou][^aeiou]{8}))$
```

(linebreaks added for readability). This works, but is there a way to do it with a more general pattern such as:

```
^[^aeiou]*[aeiou][^aeiou]*$
```

by adding a "fail if length is not 9" condition in some way?

Comment: `[^aeiou]` does not only match letters, it matches any char other than the chars inside the negated character class. What is your regex flavor? Is it used in Java? PHP? .NET?

Comment: The input only contains alphabetic characters. The regex flavour is Perl-compatible.

Comment: *"adding a "fail if length is not 9" condition in some way?"* -- the best way is to **not** check the string length using a `regex`. Use the functionality provided by the language you use to check the string length then use a `regex` to check that it contains only the accepted characters and it includes one wovel. What language do you use?

Comment: It's a website when you can supply a regex to search a dictionary of English words.

Comment: I'd love to know the downvoter's reason. Surely not anything the downvote button says: "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a lookahead to limit the length and accept only letters:

```
^(?=[a-z]{9}$)[^aeiou]*[aeiou][^aeiou]*$
```

Comment: Excellent - exactly what I was looking for, and I've confirmed it works!

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: What else does it match?

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
^(?=.{9}$)[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]*[aeiou][b-df-hj-np-tv-z]*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WqbxWX/2). Add a case insensitive flag to also match uppercase letters.

***Details**

- `^` - start of a string
- `(?=.{9}$)` - a *positive lookahead that makes sure the string contains any 9 chars (else, fail the match)
- `[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]*` - 0+ consonants
- `[aeiou]` - a vowel
- `[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]*` - 0+ consonants
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Thanks - also useful, and safer in case there are non-alphabetical characters in the wordlist.

Comment: @johnsondavies Also, `.` is faster than `[a-z]`. You do not need to check for a specific pattern when you only check the length, the consuming pattern will do it later. You will be able to use the same lookahead with all other patterns and only adjust the number inside `{X}`, no further modifications are necessary.

Comment: Thanks - that's useful.

Comment: ". is faster than [a-z]." Really? Surely it just pushes the range check work onto the consuming pattern.

Comment: @ChrisJJ `.` is a built-in construct, while `[a-z]` needs to be compiled first.

Comment: . faster to compile is not itself sufficient to make the . version faster. I do though accept your point that the . alternative has the advantage of being generic.

Answer (score 0):

> adding a "fail if length is not 9" condition in some way?"

The best way is to **not** check the string length using a `regex`.

Use the functionality provided by the language you use to check the string length then use a `regex` to check that it contains only the accepted characters and it includes one wovel.

A simple example in JavaScript (rewriting it in any other language is an easy task):

```
var input = 'some input string';

if (input.length == 9 && input.match(/[aeiou]/)) {
    console.log('Valid input (length is 9 and contains at least one wovel)');
} else {
    console.log('Invalid input');
}
```

Comment: I agree that in general this is good advice, but in my application I'm constrained to supplying a regexp.